# Save base64 image via AJAX to server

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, base64

I want to save a base64 image on a php server.
I am using webcam-easy (https://github.com/bensonruan/webcam-easy).
I inserted a a simple button on the index.html of his demo:

```
<button id="upload" onClick="postData()" style="cursor: pointer;">Send!</button>
```

and some JS:

```
    function postData() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "send.php",
  data: { 
     imgBase64: dataURL
  }
}).done(function(o) {
  console.log('saved'); 
  // If you want the file to be visible in the browser 
  // - please modify the callback in javascript. All you
  // need is to return the url to the file, you just saved 
  // and than put the image in your browser.
});
console.log(dataURL);
        
        }
```

This is how I recieve the AJAX in my send.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
  $str= $_POST['upload'];
$str=base64_decode($str);
  file_put_contents('tmp/'. 'stuff.jpg', $str);
}
```

It still is not saved to my folder. Both console logs are displayed. I don't know how to troubleshoot or solve this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably not the issue you're asking about, but when you decode the string, you need to store the result in a variable: `$str = base64_decode($str);`. If not, your just decoding the string but discard the result.

Comment: You also post the data as `imgBase64` but are trying to get it with `$_POST['upload']`. You're not posting anything called `upload`. It should be `$_POST['imgBase64']`. Because of this, the if-statement will evaluate as false and your code that saves it won't even be triggered.

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson, I added the decode variable. Yes, it is in the same folder and it is writeable.

Comment: That helped. It now puts a file down, but it can't be opened. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: If you look at the beginning of the posted string, it probably starts with something like: `data:image/jpeg;base64,`. You need to remove that part from the string before trying to decode it. It's not part of the encoded image. `$str = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $str);` (you might need to change the string to replace to match what your string starts with)

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! You saved my whole afternoon. If you post it as an answer I will hit the correct button. :)

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

#### Wrong parameter

The first issue is that you post the data as `imgBase64` but are trying to get it with `$_POST['upload'].`

Since you're not posting anything named `upload`, your if-statement: `if (isset($_POST['upload']))` will always evaluate as false and your code inside the if will never be executed.

Use `$_POST['imgBase64']` instead.

#### The base64 string

If you look at the beginning of the posted string, it probably starts with something like: `data:image/jpeg;base64,` (it's the js function `toDataUrl()` that adds that).

That is not part of the base64 encoded data so you need to remove that part from the string before trying to decode it.

It should be something like:

```
$str = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $str);
```

You might need to change the string to replace to match what your string starts with.

Answer (score 0):

#### sample Code

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
  $b64 = $_POST['upload'];
  $bin = base64_decode($b64);

  # Load GD resource from binary data
  $im = imageCreateFromString($bin);

  # Make sure that the GD library was able to load the image
  # This is important, because you should not miss corrupted or unsupported images
  if (!$im)
  {
    die('Base64 value is not a valid image');
  }

  # Specify the location where you want to save the image
  $img_file = '/files/images/filename.jpg';


  # To block any possible exploits, consider increasing the compression level
  imagejpeg($im, $img_file, 0);
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.